# How to access Synology git server remotely?

Tags: networking, vpn, git, nat, synology

I can access the git server when using the same WiFi.
But if I switch to mobile network, I can no longer access it.
DSM version 7.0

Does the NAS have a VPN or other phone home to get me back to the network or do I need network help to set this up?

Comment: What research have you done and what have you tried? Accessing resources on a private network from a public one isn't super common, but it IS well documented in many guides online.